# Route request through controller/action or straight to WebAPI from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We have an Api that requires an "Api-Key" on every request and a users "AccessToken" on all Authenticated requests. Currently when the user does a login they are given back an "AccessToken" which will be sent up with each request from there on out.

My question concerns the workflow of our current website consuming this Api. Note - The Website and Api are in different solutions/app domains, currently they are on the same box but later I doubt they will be.

Currently, the website will make all requests to the Api via its MVC controllers/action methods. At first I thought this was the easiest way to get it up and running without having to write alot of jquery to do all the requests client side. Plus the server knows its Api-Key and uses forms authentication which has the AccessToken stored.

I think we all know that if I skip out the webserver and go straight from Jquery to the WebApi it will be faster, however, in my initial review of this process I have come across a snag around authentication.

Finally the Question :)

> I know I can use the before send in ajax and modify the headers,
>   however, how does 1 get the accesstoken & the websites API-Key to the
>   client side safely to send this down the wire?
>
> Let me know if im wrong, but if I use Razor and use ViewData / ViewBag
>   and convert that into javascript in the view then surely the
>   AccessToken and Api-Key will be sitting there for the world to see
>   when they perform a viewsource?

**Current**

```
Jquery -->  MVC Action -->  WebApi
```

**Faster**

```
Jquery -->  WebApi
```

I have noticed that most Api Wrappers out there are used from within the MVC Controllers/Actions,  Thus im actually thinking that the way im doing it maybe the correct way?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your API Key a secret, then you should **keep it away from the client**.

I think you should keep proxying things as you are. If you need to secure the communications from the client to your server, then do so, but don't expose your API key to the client directly.

If the access token only lasts for a small period of time, and the methods your API offers aren't in need of heavy security, then you could expose them simply with the Access Token and keep your API Key hidden from view on the server.

I think you're proxying as you are, either way. Just a question of how tightly you want to secure the communication from the client to the server. From server to API can then be implemented either as-is or some alternate fashion you see fit.

Beyond that, I would advise to keep your controllers as dumb as you can. Let them pass the brunt of the leg-work off to a service layer that makes the API calls.

Comment: Yeah im beginning to think that this issue might be dropped from scope, doing it the current way gives us alot more flexibility! And as you say security. Cheers